# Unable to publish binaries in .net core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc, web-deployment, publish, .net-core

I am trying to self host a *.net core MVC* application. It is working fine with all `.cs` files. When I published it (`dotnet publish -f netcoreapp1.0 -c release`) through command window it is shows the following error:

> No executable found matching "bower"

and I even tried publishing with VS. It generates the binaries. But when I do `dotnet run` in command prompt it I get this error message:

> project file does not exist 'project.json'

Can anyone suggest how to do self hosting with binaries?

[image]

[image]

Comment: How do you solve the problem with 'dotnet run'?

Answer (score 15):

When running the `dotnet publish` command from the command-line, you have to make sure that your path variable contains all the relevant locations.

If you do a publish command from within Visual Studio, and look at the output in the "Build" window, you will notice that it updates the path variable before running the publish command:

[image]

From the command line, you can accomplish this by doing something like `SET Path=%PATH%;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Web\External;` be

In PowerShell you can set it as

```
$env:path += ";C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Web\External;"
```

You can also look at this GitHub issue:
[No executable found matching command "bower"](https://github.com/dotnet/cli/issues/3293)

As for your `dotnet run` question, you have to execute this command in the same directory that contains the project.json file, or use the `-p|--project` option to specify the location of the project file.  Type `dotnet run --help` on the command-line for more info.

Comment: It is publishing binaries to "bin\Debug\netcoreapp1.0\win10-x64\publish" folder. When i see this location i was not able to see "Project.json" file. Even I copied "project.json" file to above location and ran "dotnet run"  in command line. But it is giving "the system can not find the file specified".

Comment: When you run dotnet publish, you do get binaries (as you've mentioned).  Project.json is not necessary in this context, as you can just run the exe that was generated.

Answer (score 8):

I ran into this issue on an Ubuntu box and this was the fix:

```
npm install -g bower
npm install -g gulp
```

I found the fix here: https://github.com/dotnet/cli/issues/3293#issuecomment-222993063